# When finding derivatives, how do you use the filter function to return only the terms whose derivatives are not multiplied by zero, in python 3?

Tags: python, derivative

I wrote a function that, given the terms of an equation, can find derivatives. However when one of the terms is a zero, the function breaks down. How would I use filter to make sure terms that are multiplied by zero don't return?

Here's my baseline code which works but doesn't include the filter yet:

```
def find_derivative(function_terms):
    return [(function_terms[0][0]*function_terms[0][1], function_terms[0][1]-1),(function_terms[1][0]*function_terms[1][1], function_terms[1][1]-1)]
```

The function_terms[1][1]-1 reduces the power of the term of the derivative by 1.

It works like this.

Input:

```
# Represent each polynomial term with a tuple of (coefficient, power)

# f(x) = 4 x^3 - 3 x
four_x_cubed_minus_three_x = [(4, 3), (-3, 1)]
find_derivative(four_x_cubed_minus_three_x)
```

Output:

```
[(12, 2), (-3, 0)]
```

This is the correct answer of `12 x^2 - 3`

But here it breaks down:

Input:

```
# f(x) = 3 x^2 - 11
three_x_squared_minus_eleven = [(3, 2), (-11, 0)]                       
find_derivative(three_x_squared_minus_eleven)
```

It is supposed to find the derivative, given the equation.

Output:

```
((6, 1), (0, -1))
```

This has a "ghost" term of `0 * x^(-1)`; I don't want this term printed.

Expected Output:
    [(6, 1)]

Comment: You say the function "breaks down", but you failed to express what output you expect or want at that point.  I'm not clear on your notation.  Is this supposed to find `f(x-1)` given `f(x)` and the derivative?  This is not the same as finding a derivative.

Comment: Hi Prune, thanks. I'm expecting this to return `[(6, 1)]` . And it is supposed to find the derivative, given the equation f(x) = three x squared minus eleven. The `function_terms[1][1]-1` reduces the power of the term of the derivative by 1.

Comment: Got it; please edit that into your question: both the explanation and the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for tip -- done.

Comment: We've all been there.  Do what you can (I see that you did accept an answer) and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filter()` function to filter the list of tuples and then apply logic on the filtered list. Something like this should work.

```
filtered_terms = list(filter(lambda x: x[1]!=0, function_terms))
```

Now you have the tuples without constants. So rather than hard-coding derivatives, try looping through the list to get the derivative.

```
result = []
for term in filtered_terms:
    result.append((term[0]*term[1], term[1]-1))
return result
```

Comment: thanks i'm getting this error message: TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable . 

`def find_derivative(function_terms):

    filtered_terms = filter(lambda x: x[1]!=0, function_terms)

    return (filtered_terms[0][0]*filtered_terms[0][1], filtered_terms[0][1]-1), (filtered_terms[1][0]*filtered_terms[1][1], filtered_terms[1][1]-1)`

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you have to mention that. `filter()` in python 3 doesn't return a list. You need to cast it `filtered_terms = list(filter(lambda x: x[1]!=0, function_terms))`. Also, after filtering the length of the list reduces. So you might get `IndexError`. You have to change your logic accordingly. Maybe iterate over each tuple and find out the derivatives?

Comment: sorry didn't mention using Python 3! will do so from now on!

Comment: iterating over the tuples worked! thank you!! this is the final code:

Comment: `def find_derivative(function_terms):
    filtered_terms = list(filter(lambda x: x[1]!=0, function_terms))
    result = []
    for term in filtered_terms:
        result.append((term[0]*term[1], term[1]-1))
    return result`

Answer (score 0):

There is a symbolic math solver in python called sympy. Maybe it can be useful for you.

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
init_printing(use_unicode=True)

equation = 4*x**3 -3*x
diff_equation = equation.diff()
solution = diff_equation.subs({x:2})
```

Comment: thank you! this solution may be a bit above my level, but i will do a bit of research... and good to have goals/options. :)

Comment: i tried to upvote but don't have enough reputation points right now to make it stick. anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @EBGold don't worry. I'm happy if my tip could be helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Two changes:

1. Make your routine iterate through the polynomial terms, handling them one at a time, rather than depending on having exactly two terms.
2. Apply the filtering to the individual term as you encounter it.

I've extended this to also eliminate anything with a zero coefficient, as well as a zero exponent.  I added a test case with both of those *and* a negative exponent, since the symbolic differentiation theorem applies equally.

```
def find_derivative(function_terms):
    return [(term[0]*term[1], term[1]-1)
            for i, term in enumerate(function_terms)
                   if term[0] * term[1] != 0 ]

four_x_cubed_minus_three_x = [(4, 3), (-3, 1)]
print(find_derivative(four_x_cubed_minus_three_x) )

three_x_squared_minus_eleven = [(3, 2), (-11, 0)]
print(find_derivative(three_x_squared_minus_eleven) )

fifth_degree = [(1, 5), (-1, 4), (0, 3), (8, 2), (-16, 0), (1, -2)]
print(find_derivative(fifth_degree) )
```

Output:

```
[(12, 2), (-3, 0)]
[(6, 1)]
[(5, 4), (-4, 3), (16, 1), (-2, -3)]
```

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Upvote the ones you like, select the best, and move on with your programming career.

Comment: i tried to upvote but don't have enough reputation points right now to make it stick. anyway, thanks again.